# How can I create a 0 or 1 to 0 or 1 relationship that passes changes through tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

I have this setup:

[image]

Each entry of zaehler can have 0 or 1 references to module.
Each entry of module can be linked to 0 or 1 entry from zaehler.
The column modulnummer from zaehler should only be allowed to accept values that exist in module, or null. Nothing else.
No dublicate mappings allowed.
Also when a delete a entry from module that is linked to a entry from zaehler, the entry from zaehler should change to null

I tried playing around with Referential Integrity but when i enable it, there ist a mandatory 1:1 relationship on every entry.

Is this even possible to do in ms access?
What i need is something like Referential Integrity-Light.

Comment: A web search seems to indicate Yes, you can https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/define-table-relationships

Answer (score 0):

RDBMs like MSSQL, Oracle, mySql, etc. etc. generally provide (at least) two features related to your question:

- **[Constraints](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constraints-on-relational-database-model/)**: for example, a " Referential Integrity constraint"
- **[Triggers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-trigger-student-database/)**: A trigger is a stored procedure in database which automatically invokes whenever a special event in the database (e.g. "insert","update" and/or "delete") occurs.

MS-Access only provides a subset of these features.  But what you can't do in MS Access SQL, you can usually work around with VBA code.

VBA is probably the only way to accomplish everything you're looking for.  Here are some useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/add-a-record-to-a-dao-recordset
- https://accessdatabasetutorial.com/microsoft-access-database-vba/